# Word for a creator of haute couture

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for a word for a person that thinks of and makes haute-couture dresses, specifically a person that thinks about a design of for example a dress, finds all the materials needed like velvet or silk, and sews and cuts it **all alone** to obtain the final product.

Words like *designer, dressmaker* or *sewer* are not the ones I am looking for, although the only thing I did find online is *haute couture fashion designer,* but that does not please me.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to elaborate why *haute couture fashion designer* does not please you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A French term for this is [*couturier*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/couturier), and I believe it can be used in English as well.

> a person or business that designs and makes clothes for women